# pyspark: parallelize and collect order preserving

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

For spark in python, do the `sc.parallelize()` and `collect()` operations preserve order? 
For example if I have a list of elements `x`, will `sc.parallelize(x).collect()` return a list of elements in the exact same order as `x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `parallelize` and `collect` preserve order. Most of the methods in Spark don't.

Comment: reference to documentation?